# SQL Update two tables with same randomized value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, each one contains matching social security numbers.  I want to randomize the SSNs while still keeping them matching.

```
SET @NewSSN  = 000000000 + FLOOR((CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS FLOAT) / 2147483648) * (999999999 - 000000000))
```

I'd like to take that value and update both tables, matching on original SSNs.  Pseudo code, I have tried a few different variations of this:

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET [Table1].[SocSecNum], [Table2].[SocSecNum] = @NewSSN
WHERE [Table1].[SocSecNum] = [Table2].[SocSecNum]
```

Any direction where I can get this to work?

Comment: Why not have a column with a static, non changing value (PK) that matches between both tables? Then you can join/search based on that value and randomize the SSN all you want.

Comment: Why in the world are you storing SSN in plain text in the first place???? This is borderline criminal activity. That type of data should be encrypted at all times and should NEVER be used as way to join tables which is what it seems you are doing.

Comment: This is not my DB or data, it belongs to a client.  I cannot create a PK as suggested, I wouldn't have this issue if I could!  My task is to take a copy of production data and anonymize it, hence randomizing the SSNs, etc.

Comment: I might consider handing this back to your client and telling them you don't want to risk the lawsuit when this type of thing gets exposed. Keep in mind that you are partially liable if you work on this and the data gets exposed.

Comment: Duly noted and it will be addressed, thanks @Sean Lange

Comment: @Blaze You should list out your restrictions in the post. Can't add PK, can't manipulate objects, cant do this, can do that, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul's idea of a lookup table is quite reasonable.  However, it has some flaws.  For instance, duplicates are possible.  They are highly unlikely if your tables have 10 or 100 rows.  They are much more likely if they have 10,000,000 or 100,000,000.

In addition, it assumes that all values in table2 are in table1.  And, it has a problem if `table1` or `table2` has duplicate social security numbers.

So, I would suggest just using sequential numbers, randomizing the order, combining data from both tables, and removing duplicates:

```
select SocSecNum,
       right('000000000' + cast(row_number() over (order by newid()) as varchar(255)), 9) as new_SocSecNum
into #SsnMap
from (select SocSecNum
      from Table1
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select SocSecNum
      from Table2
     ) s;

update t1
    set SocSecNum = new_SocSecNum
    from Table1 t1 join
         #SsnMap s
         on t1.SocSecNum = s.SocSecNum;

update t2
    set SocSecNum = new_SocSecNum
    from Table2 t2 join
         #SsnMap s
         on t2.SocSecNum = s.SocSecNum;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a cross-reference table that maps the old SSNs to the randomized values, then perform separate `update` queries to Table1 and Table2 to set the new SSNs.

```
create table #SsnMap (OldSsn <datatype>, NewSsn <datatype>)

insert into #SsnMap (OldSsn)
select SocSecNum
from Table1
union -- distinct!
select SocSecNum
from Table2

update #SsnMap
set NewSsn = [random logic here]

update Table1
set SocSecNum = NewSsn
from #SsnMap
inner join Table1
    on SocSecNum = OldSsn

update Table2
set SocSecNum = NewSsn
from #SsnMap
inner join Table2
    on SocSecNum = OldSsn
```

Comment: Despite the absolutely horrific data that the OP is trying to manipulate this is a great way to handle this type of thing. +1

Comment: Given that SQL Server doesn't allow you to update two tables at the same time, using a temporary table is a very reasonable solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer had a good point about the distinct values between the two tables.  I updated my answer with a distinct union and a separate update assuming the OP would use the same random logic proposed in the question.  I think your suggestion of a sequential number is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option, you can use HashBytes() to create a consistant map.

Two simple updates with no need of a temp map.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SSN varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('555667777'),
('123456789')

Select SSN
      ,Masked = abs(cast(HashBytes('MD5',SSN) as int))
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SSN         Masked
555667777   246591824
123456789   459427083
```